# How do I get valgrind to skip errors I do not want when debugging with gdb?

Tags: gdb, valgrind

I run valgrind and it comes up with a particular error I am interested in (others are false positives). When running gdb I want to get straight to that error. How would I go about this? Otherwise it would take ages due to the high number of other errors. It's an invalid free error I am interested in, can I suppress other types of error, or can I specify perhaps line numbers or addresses where I am happy to stop the program?

Or am I stuck having to do it the hard way?

I'm using valgrind 3.9.0 and GDB 7.4-2012.04 on Linux Mint 13.

Comment: Your question is exceedingly unclear. What are you actually running under GDB, and how does Valgrind enter the picture?

Comment: Did you try --vgdb-error?  See "man valgrind".

Comment: One problem is that the number of errors beforehand may be different each time I run the program. However I was able to solve the problem by going through each error until I got to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can instruct valgrind to skip the next 1000 errors like this:

```
(gdb) monitor v.set vgdb-error 1000
```

Also set a break point at the start of the code you are interested in testing for memory errors. When the breakpoint is reached then set vgdb-error to 0 before continuing, and gdb will once again stop at each error.

Apparently you can also give valgrind a list of errors to suppress, or valgrind can be used to generate the list automatically. See  http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core.html#manual-core.suppress

Note the poster is talking about a situation where he is debugging a program using valgrind's gdbserver and gdb. This is a powerful technique for adding memory error checking to your gdb session. See http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/manual-core-adv.html#manual-core-adv.gdbserver